# Assigning values to a list based on a string search in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe ('frame') that has multiple columns. In column 2 ('col2'), I want it to search for a set of characters (' 42 ') (spaces included) and then I want it to search for 'ID' in column 1 ('col1'). I then have values in columns 6 and 7 ('col6','col7') that I want to assign to a list (lets call it 'vals42'), but only the values from the index of where we found ' 42 ' up until the index where we found 'ID'. I then want this to start over and look for the next ' 42 ' and so on.

The other tricky part is that the first 'ID' is actually before the first ' 42 ', so I need it to start at the second 'ID' so I don't have an invalid range.

The other thing, I have a bunch of NaN's that exist in my dataframe.

I am trying to do this by getting the index of the ' 42 ' and the index of the 'ID' and then creating a subset of the pandas dataframe, and then when it goes on to the next ' 42 ' it creates another subset and so on.

In some of my previous code, I already figured out how to get the values from 'col6' and 'col7' into a list. What I am struggling with (I think) is getting the logic to check out for checking for these characters and getting the indexes of them.

```
for var in frame:
    if (frame['col2'].str.contains(' 42 ')) == True:
        begin = frame.index.get_loc(frame.name)
    elif (frame['col1'].str.contains('ID')) == True:
        end = frame.index.get_loc(frame.name)
        subset = frame[begin:end]
        for column in subset[['col6','col7']]:
             ColumnContents = pd.concat([subset['col6'], subset['col7']])
             ColumnContents = pd.to_numeric(ColumnContents, errors = 'coerce')
             vals42 = ColumnContents[ColumnContents.apply(lambda x: x > 0 and x < 20)]
```

The pandas dataframe is made by reading in csv Excel files from a folder I have. Below is an example of the general format of the dataframe: The x's symbolize data that isn't important.

```
      col1       col2          .  .  .   col6      col7 
0      ID        xxx                     NaN       NaN
1      xxx     67812 LT 42 01
2      xxx       xxx                     NaN       NaN
3      xxx       xxx                     NaN       NaN
4      xxx       xxx                     NaN       NaN
.
.
.
17    xxx        xxx                     0.543     1670
18    xxx        xxx                     0.321     8954
.
.
.
29    ID         xxx                      NaN      NaN
30    xxx        12976 42 01
```

So in this example, the values I want to assign start at index 17 and go all the way down to index 28. At index 29 though, we get a new 'ID' so it starts over. The number of rows for which values exist in columns 6 and 7 is not necessarily the same all the time. Also, the number is not always ' 42 ', it could be something else, but once I get it for one number I can apply it to others, so I am using ' 42 ' as an example. Ideally, I want the numbers from 'col6' and 'col7' to assign to the list if they meet the conditions (x>0, x<20).

EDIT: The 'ID' literally is just 'ID'. There is no special string associated with it in each instance, so the 'ID' in row 0 and row 29 are exactly the same. The x'd out data is not the same as the 'ID' or the '67812 LT 42 01'. The x'd out data is its own entire unique thing. Each x'd out cell has its entirely own unique set of characters in it, so it won't match up with the 'ID' or the '67812 LT 42 01'.

So the thing is, I know the bottom four lines of code work in my other scenario where I am just getting the values from the entire dataframe.

When I ran this I got the error "the truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: Could you provide the code to create an example dataframe with a few records.

Comment: I edited for what the dataframe looks like while also going into more detail, thanks

Comment: Is "ID" literally "ID", or are you using that as a stand-in for a unique ID? In your example, both row 0 and row 29 have a value of ID. Is it really the same value? What about the intervening rows; you have them x'd out as if they are irrelevant, but are the same value as row 0, col1? And I have the same question for col2; e.g., are rows 2 through 29 also populated with `67812 LT 42 01`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question. In short, the ID's are the same, and the x'd out data is not the same as the 'ID' or '67812 LT 42 01' and is its own entirely unique thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out if anyone is curious for future reference:

```py
start = True
vals42 = pd.Series()
for index2, rows  in frame[1:].iterrows():
      if (' 42 ' in rows['col2']):
           begin = index2
           start = True
      elif (start is True) & ('ID' in rows['col1']):
           end = index2
           subset = frame[begin:end]
           for column in subset[['col6','col7']]:
                ColumnContents = pd.concat([subset['col6'], subset['col7']])
                ColumnContents = pd.to_numeric(ColumnContents, errors = 'coerce')
                subsetTotal = ColumnContents[ColumnContents.apply(lambda x: x > 0 and x < 20)]
                vals42 = pd.concat([vals42, subsetTotal])
                start = False
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56637415/5) to the question [Assigning values to a list based on a string search in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637415/assigning-values-to-a-list-based-on-a-string-search-in-a-pandas-dataframe) by the OP [JJXS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11660615/jjxs) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>